# Select and copy page range from worksheet

Tags: c#, .net, excel, excel-interop

How do you select a range based on the "page" borders defined in "Page Break View" in excel?

I have an .xlsx with a worksheet that has 6 area defined "pages" (possibly referred to as the print area?). Based on data contained in an SQL table, I intend to perform some arithmetic and the feed the data values into the into the worksheet and, depending on the number categories, need to duplicate a specific "Page" range.

This is a court document for costs budgeting called "Precedent H" and is available from justice.gov.uk at the following URL:

https://www.justice.gov.uk/downloads/courts/cpr/precedent-h-april-2016.xlsx

I'm looking to duplicate the two contingent cost categories on the first worksheet programmatically where a budget has multiple contingent cost categories (Contingent Cost A/B/C/D/etc). I using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass() to access/open the document, then using a combination of Range.Find and Range.Offset to assign the values. I have toyed with using UsedRange and then a split function to get the last cell then count backwards with an offset to get the first cell in the page, but I wondered if there was a simpler method to get the range?

Answer (score 0):

Found a working solution to get a specific range:

```
Range rngTo = wsBreakdown.Cells.SpecialCells(XlCellType.xlCellTypeLastCell, Type.Missing);
Range rngFrom = rngTo.Offset[-24, -9];
```

then just looped round and copy/pasted the area:

```
Range rngPaste = rngFrom.Offset[0, 1];
for (int i = 1; i == noPages; i++)
{
    Range rngCopy = wsBreakdown.Range[rngFrom.Address, rngTo.Address];
    rngCopy.Copy(Type.Missing);
    rngPaste.PasteSpecial(XlPasteType.xlPasteAllUsingSourceTheme, XlPasteSpecialOperation.xlPasteSpecialOperationNone, false, false);

    rngTo = wsBreakdown.Cells.SpecialCells(XlCellType.xlCellTypeLastCell, Type.Missing);
    rngFrom = rngTo.Offset[-24, -9];
    rngPaste = rngFrom.Offset[0, 1];
}
```